# Labels not showing in the GUI (Maybe because of background picture?)

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, scenebuilder

Ive been trying to make a chat for a week or so now, the goal is that the chat will become an animated chat that contains figures and background rooms. so far ive created the gui with the background and has now come to the point where i want to add my characters if someone connects. The GUI is created in JavaFx Scenebuilder and the stylesheet is created in CSS.

The idea behind this is that when ever someone connects to the server they are given a chat person and then a random spot on the screen to stand (later on il implement movement :) ) but my problem is that when i try to create a label with the picture attached the GUI doesnt seem to show the picture (as shown in the picture example below) my code looks as following:

```
        Label test = new Label();
    test.setStyle("build.css");
    test.setText("Here i am");
    test.setVisible(true);

    Image img = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Figur.png"));
    Label test2 = new Label("", new ImageView(img));
    test2.setLayoutX(50);
    test2.setLayoutY(30);
    test2.setVisible(true);
```

the code above is 2 attempts to create labels and the Gui still doesnt actually show them. My current thought is that the labels are hiding behind the background picture of the GUI because ive simply added the picture though CSS (with the following code):

```
#AnchorPane{-fx-background-image:url('Background.JPG');}
```

can anyone help me and guide me to how i can get my labels to appear inside the picture and be visible ? :)

Thank you in advance!

[image: Picture of my program]

Comment: Anyone who can see what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 1st attempt is wrong at line

```
test.setStyle("build.css");
```

Load your CSS stylesheets like as follows

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("build.css").toExternalForm());
```

and apply the custom id selector defined in the loaded css to the test label as

```
test.setId("myTestId");
```

Your 2nd attempt is correct. Show how you are adding these labels to the scene.
**UPDATE:** To add labels dynamically do follwoings.
In the controller class of your FXML file, link to the anchor pane and add labels to it:

```
@FXML private AnchorPane anchorPane; // where fx:id = anchorPane
anchorPane.getChildren().addAll(test, test2);
```

Comment: The problem is im not adding labels to the scene my self :S so far ive only used the gui builder to create my labels. but seeing as i need to create an x number of labels depending on how many is online i need to know how to add them to my AnchorPane :)?

Comment: Thank you but where does it actually add them? do i have to set my own x and y cordinates to add them to a specefic point on the screen? (im guessing i have to)

Comment: Sadly i am still unable to actually see the label :S